# Flatten properties into List in EF Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Lets say I have an entity which can reference other rows in its table, defined like this:

```cs
MyEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public bool isRelevant { get; set; }

    public virtual List<MyEntity> Children
}
```

Attempting something like:

```cs
var result = await MyEntities
                    .SelectMany(o => new List<string> { o.Id, o.ParentId })
                    .ToListAsync();
```

This however results in a runtime error:

> The LINQ expression could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable'...

How can I select all of the `MyEntity` `Id` AND `ParentId` values as a single list without reverting to client-side evaluation?

To be clear, I would like the result from the database to be something like:

`["Id1", "parentId1", "Id2", "ParentId2"]`

Answer (score 0):

I assume just the parents not the children

create class:

```
public class Parent{

public string Id {get;set;}
public string ParentId {get;set;}

}
```

then

```
var result = MyEntities.select(x => new Parent(){Id = x.Id, ParentId = x.ParentId}).toList();
```

edit:

To flatten to string list something like this, though you would run it against the ef resultset not directly against ef,

Though i cant think of any reason you would want to do that, this will do all the properties in the class, if i understood question this will do list of all values:

```
var properties = result.SelectMany(x => x.GetType().GetProperties().Select(y => y.GetValue(x))).ToList();
```

you would probaly need to tweak it, adding a where clause, to ignore the properties you dont want included as this one will do all the properties, also might need to add toString() to getValue

so in your case:

```
var properties = result.SelectMany(x => x.GetType().GetProperties().Where(i => i.Name == "Id" || i.Name == "ParentId").Select(y => y.GetValue(x))).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not a flattened list of properties, I've added an example at the end  of my question to clarify  what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Bolly ok well that makes no sense really :)

Comment: @Bolly i edited answer with a way of doing that with list of string

Comment: "I cant think of any reason you would want to do that": for example, because both Child and Parent are the same type, think of a `GetChildAndParent().Select(...)` sort of query where you want a property from both without having to merge results later. Not sure if you tried your updated answer, but I get the same runtime error: "could not be translated". It seems like EFCore really doesn't like merging properties on the same entity

Comment: @Bolly I have provided you the solution which does exactly what you want at the bottom of the post above, works fine for me. doesnt matter if they're the same type lol, there is no reason to flatten into a string list like this at all. Tested again this morning and works fine

Comment: What version of EFCore did you test in? Because I get an error. Prior to EFCore 3.x, this would silently evaluate on the client and you wouldn't get an error

Comment: @Bolly running fine on webapi net 6, working without issue, this wouldnt be run against efcore anyway it would run against the result set you wouldnt run it directly on efcore

Comment: In my case it's an initial selector for an EFCore query so it is run on EFCore. I appreciate your help though, if this was just a LINQ question then you would be 100% correct :)

Comment: @Bolly all you have to do is run it against the efcore result :D

Comment: That means if I want to extend the query, I need to do `{parent.select(...), children.select(...)}` all the way through because they are still separate properties, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Bolly there is little point to this solution in all honesty i cannot think of any reason for it,  as you can see from answers :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **List** of **String** to store an anonymous value object.

Please use **object**  or **Parent class** including id and parent id as properties.

My opinion is to use class called  "Parent"

`.Select(o => new { o.Id, o.ParentId })`

or

`.Select(o => new Parent { Id = o.Id, ParentId = o.ParentId })`

Comment: The syntax: new List<string> { o.Id, o.ParentId }) is list initialization, not anonymous object creation. You can try this to confirm: `var ls = new List<string> { "one", "two" };` Your two solutions don't flatten the properties either, I've added an example to clarify what I'm looking for.